# AngularJS ng-click seems to not work

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller, angularjs-ng-click

I have an md-select that has inside it an md-option. In the md-option tag I have an ng-click that points to my function that is defined. The problem is that it seems to never get to my function when I click an option from the list.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <md-select placeholder="{{getIntervalName()}}"  ng-model="intervalSelected">
            <md-option ng-repeat="item in intervals" value="{{item.name}}" ng-click="changeInterval(item)">
                {{item.name}}
            </md-option>
            </md-select>
            <div style="overflow: auto;">
                <div id="parentDivChart" style="{{changeWidth()}};height:400px">
                     <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="datta"
                        chart-labels="labels" chart-options="myoptions" chart-legend="legend">
                    </canvas> 
                <div tc-chartjs-legend chart-legend="legend"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And this is my function defined in the controller:

```
function changeInterval(item) {
                    console.log("change intervaaaalll");
                    $scope.default_interval ="day";
                    intrvl = item.value;
                    setItem("interval", item.value);
                    $scope.loadChart();
                };
```

It does not write to the console anything, that means it never reaches my function. Does anybody have an idea why ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that `changeInterval` is private function. try this `$scope.changeInterval = function() { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been better if you had provided the code where you create the controller.
However, I think you should create the method `changeInterval(item)` in this way:

```
var nameOfYourApp = angular.module(‘nameOfYourApp’, []);
nameOfYourApp.controller('nameOfYourController', function($scope) {
          $scope.changeInterval = function(item) {
                    console.log("change intervaaaalll");
                    $scope.default_interval ="day";
                    intrvl = item.value;
                    setItem("interval", item.value);
                    $scope.loadChart();    
          }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Write `"$scope.changeInterval=changeInterval;"` in your controller

or

use `"$scope.changeInterval=function (item) {...};"`

Answer (score 0):

As you want to use the changeInterval method on the scope you have to add it to the scope as follows:

In the controller:

```
$scope.changeInterval(item) {
                    console.log("change intervaaaalll");
                    $scope.default_interval ="day";
                    intrvl = item.value;
                    setItem("interval", item.value);
                    $scope.loadChart();
                };
```

**Don't forget to include $scope as a dependency for your controller.**

E.g.:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

Now as the changeInterval function is assigned to a variable on the scope it can be invoked on the view.

Answer (score 0):

Since you changeInterval() is a private function to the controller, you can't access it. You need to make it public (bind it to a variable of the controller).

You should go with this approach:

```
$scope.changeInterval = changeIntervalapproach;
```

If you're using the view model approach with controllerAs then use:

```
vm.changeInterval = changeInterval;
```